# i want to hide single parameter from Dialog box in action menu item in ax 2012

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012

I want to hide single parameter from Dialog box in action menu item in ax 2012
I use controller class with action menu item,
any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use atributte SysOperationControlVisibilityAttribute(false) on datacontract parameter method.

https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/palleagermark/archive/2011/11/30/hiding-a-data-member-attribute-from-dialogs